# How to load death scene in C#/unitygames?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

haven't posted on here before but I have been trying for a while to create a game and would like a death/game over sort of scene to appear when the player loses all 3 of their lives. I have a functioning game manager and my player can lose lives (they have 3). This is all being done in unity games and is 2d (idk if that helps). I currently have other stuff in my scene loader script that works fine so I will post the whole thing but I am having issues with the bottom most code!
Thank you!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
  public string scenename;
  public GameManager GM;
 

 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
  {
    if(collision.tag == "Player")
    {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(scenename);
    }
  }


    private void Deathscene()
    {
      if(GM.LifeTotal == 0)
        {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(Bob); 
        }
    }

}

Gamemanager script 

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public int PotionsCollected = 0;
public int LifeTotal = 3;

    public Text PotionsOutput;
    public Text LifeOutput;
    void Update()
    {
        PotionsOutput.text = "Potions: " + PotionsCollected;
          LifeOutput.text = "Life: " + LifeTotal;
    }

    public void CollectPotion()
    {
        PotionsCollected++;
    }
    public void UsePotion()
    {
        PotionsCollected--;
    }
    public void LoseLife()
    {
        LifeTotal--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "Bob"?

Comment: Bob was just a temporary name for my death scene. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is from your Unity Editor go to File->Build Settings and then drag and drop inside the active scenes window your death scene.

Then an index will be generated on the right side of the window and you can use that index to load the scene. like this:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Use your generated index");
```

NOTE: Use your index as a number and not as a string.

UPDATED Solution:

```
public void LoseLife() 
{
    LifeTotal--; 

    if(LifeTotal <= 0)
    {
         SceneManager.LoadScene("Use your generated index");
    }
}
```

I supposse `LoseLife()` it's called when the enemy attacks your player.

Comment: Is the GM part correct though? Will this help to lead my new scene when the players life total is at 0.

Comment: The "Deathscene" function when is it triggered?

Comment: When you decrease the "LifeTotal" you should also check if it reaches 0. If it does then you can call the "SceneManager.LoadScene()"

Comment: Death scene function is trigged when player loses all 3 lives. How would I check when the LifeTotal reaches 0? (sorry I am very new to all this and am still learning)

Comment: Can you please share the code where you decrease the "LifeTotal" from your GameManager script? It will be easier for me to help you out

Comment: Sure thing here you go!

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public int PotionsCollected = 0;
public int LifeTotal = 3;

    public Text PotionsOutput;
    public Text LifeOutput;
    void Update()
    {
        PotionsOutput.text = "Potions: " + PotionsCollected;
          LifeOutput.text = "Life: " + LifeTotal;
    }

    public void CollectPotion()
    {

Comment: public void UsePotion()
    {
        PotionsCollected--;
    }
    public void LoseLife()
    {
        LifeTotal--;
    }
}

Comment: Please share the code on your main post, like you did with the "SceneLoader" script. You can edit your post.

Comment: That is the whole gamemanager script but this is the specific Decrease life part.    public 
    public void LoseLife()
    {
        LifeTotal--;
    }
}

Comment: Have now added it :)